# PHP drop down menu from database

Tags: php, html, mysqli, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to recreate a make a booking form. They have a drop down select option with 3 values from the room table in the database. In the room table I have the values roomID, roomname, roomtype and beds. I need to have roomname, roomtype and beds displayed as one option in the drop down. So the 3 values will be on the same line if that makes sense. So for example it will say Brown, Double, 2beds and then I can select the options and will view another set of data. I currently know how to make a drop down with only one value in the line but how would I make a drop down menu that presents 3 values from a table?

Below is my code so far:

```
<?php
include "config.php"; 
$db = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", DBUSER, DBPASSWORD, DBDATABASE);
$query = $db->query("select roomname, roomtype, beds from room"); 

echo '<select room="roomname">'; 


while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo '<option value="'.$row['roomname'].'">'.$row['roomname'].'</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
?>
```

Comment: Please post some codes what you had tried.

Comment: @Gnanavel just did.

Comment: You're mixing APIs. You connect with `mysqli` but try to fetch with `PDO`. Do you have error reporting turned on? You really should be seeing errors.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are expecting.If you want to show roomname, roomtype, beds in one line just concatenate it.

```
<?php
  include "config.php"; 
  $db = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", DBUSER, DBPASSWORD, DBDATABASE);
  $query = $db->query("select id,roomname, roomtype, beds from room"); 
  echo '<select name="roomname">'; 
  while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['roomname'].'-'.$row['roomtype'].'-'.$row['beds from room'].'</option>';
  }
  echo '</select>';
?>
```

Comment: The main issue is not the displayed value. This code will never fetch anything from the database because it mixes `mysqli` and `PDO`.